# Truck will not start after installing new battery when first installed turned over fine. No headlights no clicking when turning key

Tags: electrical

Truck initially would not start old  battery was no good ..installed new battery worked fine when installed ....tried starting two days later after it sat for two days ...no lights and would not start ...no click when turning

Comment: Did you leave any lights on? Interior?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Recheck your connections. If you didn't leave anything on which would have drained it, I think the next logical step would be to check the connections at the battery which may be at fault.

Comment: Is the battery being charged by the alternator? Has the charging system been tested?